# Filepicker.io - Is there a simple way to migrate photos stored using paperclip to filepicker.io in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, filepicker.io

I am looking to integrate filepicker.io into my web app but the problem is that some of my models are already using paperclip to store images to S3.

I would like to avoid having to clutter up my code with logic on wether the model is now using a filepicker url or still using paperclip uploaded image and just migrate all photos to use filepicker using a rake task.

Has anyone else come across this problem and if so what solution do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the store endpoint available at https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl-store to migrate the files you have to use filepicker.io URLs